# maven not found in jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, devops, slave

I tried to use Jenkins slave for pipeline run. even though I add the maven home to the path, issue comes as below.

```
pipeline {

  agent { label 'test' }
  
  stages {  

    stage('Maven') {
            steps {
                sh "wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz"
                sh "ls"
                sh "pwd"
                sh "ls /home/jenkins/workspace/check"
                sh "tar -xvzf /home/jenkins/workspace/check/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz"
                sh "ls /home/jenkins/workspace/check/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin"
                sh "export PATH==/home/jenkins/workspace/check/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH"
                sh "echo $PATH"
                sh "mvn -version"
                
                //sh "sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/mvn" "mvn" "/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn" 0"
                //sh "sudo update-alternatives --set mvn /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn"
       }
        
    }
      
  }
```

This is the issue. which says maven not found even it has the mvn file. Appreciate it if anyone can give the clue.

```
    + ls /home/jenkins/workspace/check/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
m2.conf
mvn
mvn.cmd
mvnDebug
mvnDebug.cmd
mvnyjp
[Pipeline] sh
+ export PATH==/home/jenkins/workspace/check/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn -version
/home/jenkins/workspace/check@tmp/durable-66731e8b/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/check@tmp/durable-66731e8b/script.sh: mvn: not found
```

Comment: Check the user permission in the slave machine. It should have access to execute maven.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This has solved by properly config the env path.